# Create a matrix of c_short_type arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, ctypes

I have array of type `<class '__main__.c_short_Array_40000'>` which has `totalSamples = 40000` elements. I create it using ctypes convention `buffer = (ctypes.c_int16 * totalSamples)()`. Now I need to create dozens of such arrays, so I need to pack them in a matrix (lets say 32x40000), where each element is of type `<class '__main__.c_short_Array_40000'>`. How do I do that? Later I will iterate through that matrix and provide each row of matrix to `ctypes.byref(myMatrixRow)` function, which requires `<class '__main__.c_short_Array_40000'>` as input.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep multiplying for more dimensions:

```py
buffer = (ctypes.c_int16 * 40000 * 32)()
```

The above is equivalent to C `int16_t buffer[32][40000];`.  Note the dimensions are declared in reverse in Python, but you will still access like C:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> buffer = (ctypes.c_int16 * 40000 * 32)()
>>> buffer
<__main__.c_short_Array_40000_Array_32 object at 0x00000227681FFBC0>
>>> buffer[0]
<__main__.c_short_Array_40000 object at 0x00000227681FFC40>
>>> buffer[31]
<__main__.c_short_Array_40000 object at 0x00000227681FFCC0>
>>> buffer[31][39999]
0
```

Comment: I found strange thing implementing this in python. If I create a buffer: `bufferAMax = (ctypes.c_int16 * 40000 * 10)()` I get `<__main__.c_short_Array_40000_Array_10 object at 0xb4d157b0>`. But each array in the buffer has same address. For example: `bufferAMax[0]` gives `<__main__.c_short_Array_40000 object at 0xb4d15940>`, while `bufferAMax[9]` again gives `<__main__.c_short_Array_40000 object at 0xb4d15940>`. I think something is wrong here isn't it?

Comment: @user2963789 No, ctypes is creating proxy objects, but you didn’t assign them to variables and they immediately are freed. The next one happens to allocate at the same address. Assign the references to names and they will be different